Uniqueness equivalent to existence for a finite dimensional square linear system
Could somebody please explain to be why for a finite dimensional square linear system, the uniqueness of a solution is equivalent to its existence?
As far as I see, "finite dimensional square linear system" means a system of $m\in\mathbb{N}, m\geq 2$, linear equations with $m$ variables.
But obviously,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\end{pmatrix}
$$
has infinitely many solutions for $a_1\in\mathbb{R}, a_2=0$ so that the statement cannot be true without further assumptions.
I am still confused.

$null(A) = {\mathbf{0}}$

The statement is that, for a square matrix $A = (a_{ij})_{1\leq i,j \leq n}$ the following conditions are equivalent:
1). for any $b\in \mathbb R^n$, the equation $Ax=b$ has at most one solution.
2). for any $b \in \mathbb R^n$ the equation $Ax=b$ has at least one solution.
This follows, for example, from the rank-nullity theorem which asserts that the dimension $r(A)$ of the image $\{Ax: x\in \mathbb R^n\}\leq \mathbb R^n$ and the dimension $n(A)$ of the kernel of $A$, $\ker(A) = \{x \in \mathbb R^n: Ax=0\}$ satisfy $r(A)+n(A) = n$ (the dimension of $\mathbb R^n$). Thus the map $x \mapsto Ax$ has image $\mathbb R^n$ if and only if $r(A)=n$, if and only if $n(A)=0$, if and only if $\ker(A) = \{0\}$.

I now understand that uniqueness implies existence. But why does existence imply uniqueness. There are linear systems $Ax=b$ which have infinitely many solutions.
